# Replace items in list with items in tuple of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

currently I am trying to unify license names in rpm packages.

Therefore I parse rpms, get the license information as lists and want to compare these list with a lookup table I build.

Here is an example:

```
lic = ['GPLv2', ' & ', 'LGPLv2+', ' & ', 'LGPLv2.1+', ' | ', 'LGPLv3+']

duplicates = (
            ('GPL-2.0', 'GPL-2', 'GPLv2', 'GPLv2.0'),
            ('GPL-2.0+', 'GPL-2+', 'GPLv2+', 'GPLv2.0+'),
            ('GPL-3.0', 'GPL-3', 'GPLv3', 'GPLv3.0'),
            ('GPL-3.0+', 'GPL-3+', 'GPLv3+', 'GPLv3.0+'),
            ('LGPL-2.0', 'LGPLv2.0', 'LGPLv2', 'LGPL2'),
            ('LGPL-2.0+', 'LGPLv2.0+', 'LGPLv2+', 'LGPL2+'),
            ('LGPL-2.1', 'LGPLv2.1', 'LGPL2.1'),
            ('LGPL-2.1+', 'LGPLv2.1+', 'LGPL2.1+'),
            ('LGPL-3.0', 'LGPLv3.0', 'LGPLv3', 'LGPL3'),
            ('LGPL-3.0+', 'LGPLv3.0+', 'LGPLv3+', 'LGPL3+')
            )
```

What would be the most efficient and most pythonic way of replacing all occurrences of any element in `duplicates` in `lic` with the corresponding first element of each tuple?

eg: *GPLv2* needs to be replaced with *GPL-2.0*, *LGPLv2+* with *LGPL-2.0+* and so on.

I am on Python 3.5.2

Comment: You probably need to use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over your `lic` and compare each of its elements with `duplicates` and if you find match replace that element with first element of matching tuple.

```
lic = ['GPLv2', ' & ', 'LGPLv2+', ' & ', 'LGPLv2.1+', ' | ', 'LGPLv3+']

duplicates = (
            ('GPL-2.0', 'GPL-2', 'GPLv2', 'GPLv2.0'),
            ('GPL-2.0+', 'GPL-2+', 'GPLv2+', 'GPLv2.0+'),
            ('GPL-3.0', 'GPL-3', 'GPLv3', 'GPLv3.0'),
            ('GPL-3.0+', 'GPL-3+', 'GPLv3+', 'GPLv3.0+'),
            ('LGPL-2.0', 'LGPLv2.0', 'LGPLv2', 'LGPL2'),
            ('LGPL-2.0+', 'LGPLv2.0+', 'LGPLv2+', 'LGPL2+'),
            ('LGPL-2.1', 'LGPLv2.1', 'LGPL2.1'),
            ('LGPL-2.1+', 'LGPLv2.1+', 'LGPL2.1+'),
            ('LGPL-3.0', 'LGPLv3.0', 'LGPLv3', 'LGPL3'),
            ('LGPL-3.0+', 'LGPLv3.0+', 'LGPLv3+', 'LGPL3+')
            )

for idx, i in enumerate(lic):
    for match in duplicates:
        if i in match:
            lic[idx] = match[0]
            break

print(lic)
```

Output:

```
['GPL-2.0', ' & ', 'LGPL-2.0+', ' & ', 'LGPL-2.1+', ' | ', 'LGPL-3.0+']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the `duplicates` tuple of tuples to a dict first. like so:

```
duplicates = {k: v for k, *v in duplicates}  # {'GPL-2.0': ['GPL-2', 'GPLv2', 'GPLv2.0'], ...}
```

and then do:

```
lic_clean = [next((k for k, v in duplicates.items() if x in v), x) for x in lic]
```

which produces:

```
['GPL-2.0', ' & ', 'LGPL-2.0+', ' & ', 'LGPL-2.1+', ' | ', 'LGPL-3.0+']
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to keep the seperators, so I can reassemble the original license afterwards